# Word problem. System of equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Where C is the total cost in pounds, a is a fixed charge, n the number of calls and b the price of each call in pence. When the number of calls was 104, the bill came to £58.30, and when the number was 67 the bill was £ 50.90. Find the fixed charge and the cost of each call.

$$C = a + \frac{ nb }{100}$$

I came up with this

$$58.30 = a + \frac{ 104b }{100}$$

$$50.90 = a + \frac{ 67b }{100}$$

$$4 / 58.30 = a + \frac{ 104b }{100}$$

$$14.58 = a + \frac{ 26b }{100}$$

$$a = 14.58 - \frac{ 26b }{100}$$

$$50.90 = ( 14.58 - \frac{ 26b }{100} ) + \frac{ 67b }{100}$$

$$50.90 = 14.58 + \frac{ 41b }{100}$$

$$36.32 = \frac{ 41b }{100}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** No idea what you're doing.

The first two equations after "I came up with this" are certainly correct.

Subtract corresponding sides to remove $a$ and you have an equation to solve for $b$. Once you then have $b$, put it back into either of the first two equations and you then have an equation to solve for $a$.

Then you are done.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Thanks.